# Formulário não envia para e-mail (PHP)

Tags: php

Tenho duas páginas criadas, a index.php e a processaForm.php. A primeira conta com o form e a segunda se encarrega de pegar os dados e enviá-lo para meu e-mail. Mas, apesar de colocar ambos os arquivos no servidor (000webhost) e enviar, meu e-mail (gmail) não recebe nada. Sou iniciante então preciso de toda ajuda que puder :D

**index.php**

```
<?php

$msg = 0;
@$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

?>
```

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
        if ($msg=="enviado"):
    ?>
    <h1>Mensagem enviada</h1>

    <?php else: ?>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><h3>Formulário de contato</h3></legend>
        <form action="processaForm.php" method="post">
            <label for="name">Nome:</label><br>
            <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" required><br>
            <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label><br>
            <input id="telefone" type="tel" name="telefone" requerid><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" requerid><br>
            <label for="assunto">Assunto:</label><br>
            <textarea id="assunto" name="assunto"> </textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar">
        </form>
    </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>

</body>
```

**processaForm.php**

```
<?php

$para = "meuemail@gmail.com";
$assunto = "Consulta agendada";
$nome = $_REQUEST['nome'];
$fone = $_REQUEST['telefone'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['assunto'];

    $corpo = "<strong> Mensagem de contato </strong><br><br>"; 
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Nome: </strong> $nome"; 
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Telefone: </strong> $fone";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Email: </strong> $email";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Mensagem: </strong> $msg";   

    $header = "From: $email Reply-to: $email";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset = utf-8";

@mail($para, $assunto, $corpo, $header);

header("location:index.php?msg=enviado");
?>
```

Comment: Tira o `@` de tudo e executa pra ver. Também veja se voce configurou o `php.ini`, lá verifica as credenciais do SMTP

Comment: Essa parte: "Também veja se voce configurou o php.ini, lá verifica as credenciais do SMTP" eu não entendi nada, desculpe. Sou bem iniciante mesmo rsrs

Comment: Ok, mas voce tirou o **@** e executou o código pra ver se aparece algum erro ?

Comment: Retirei, upei os files no servidor e mesmo assim não enviou.

Comment: Mano, eu uso o xampp, pelo servidor local não tem como testar envio de e-mail. Ou tem e eu estou lerdando?

Comment: Tem como porém tem que configurar, eu recomendo voce usar isso então: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer lá tem a documentação de como usar

Comment: veja na internet tutorias de como usar o PHPMailer, no youtube voce acha varios. Não é muito recomendado usar apenas a função `mail()` nativa do PHP

Comment: Entendo, vou estudar sobre.